# Can anyone find the syntax error in my table join statement?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I feel like I am making an obvious mistake here but I have been looking at it too long to see. Whenever I run this line:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' in ', city, ', ', statecode) AS 'Publisher Name and Location', COUNT(ISBN) AS '# Books', Max(Length(Title)) AS 'Longest Title', Min(Length(Title)) AS 'Shortest Title', 
FROM publisher
JOIN book ON (publisher.publisherID = book.publisherID)
WHERE INSTR(name, 'read') > 0 
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(ISBN) > 1;
```

I get an error that says there is a syntax error at 'FROM publisher JOIN book ON (publisher.publisherID = book.publisherID) WHERE INS'

Comment: Object identifiers need to be put in double quotes `"` not single quotes `'` so it should be `AS "Publisher Name and Location"`

Answer (score 1):

remove the comma

```
AS 'Shortest Title',  FROM publisher 
                   ^----here
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `,` infront of  `FROM publisher JOIN book`

Answer (score 1):

Try this by removing the comma in `AS 'Shortest Title',  FROM publisher` :

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' in ', city, ', ', statecode) AS "Publisher Name 
and Location", COUNT(ISBN) AS "# Books", 
Max(Length(Title)) AS "Longest Title", Min(Length(Title)) AS "Shortest Title" 
FROM publisher JOIN book ON (publisher.publisherID = book.publisherID) 
WHERE INSTR(name, 'read') > 0 GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(ISBN) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any possibility that its because you have a `WHERE` and a `HAVING` in the same statement?